# Categorical data: convert into binary encoding by adding a new dimension

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, categorical-data

Every feature in my dataset has three categories and is currently encoded with the integers 0, 1 and 2. Instead of one-hot, I want to encode it into a binary type of coding, where 0 is replaced with [0,0], 1 is replaced with [0,1] and 2 is replaced with [1,1]. How would I do this without using a for loop?

Let's say my data looks like this:

```
  [[1, 2, 0],
   [2, 0, 1]]
```

The result should add a dimension -

```
  [[[0., 1.],
    [1., 1.],
    [0., 0.]],

   [[1., 1.],
    [0., 0.],
    [0., 1.]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with

```
(a.ravel()[:,None]>np.arange(a.max())).astype(int)[:,::-1].reshape((2,-1,2))
Out[353]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [0, 0]],
       [[1, 1],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]]])
```

---

```
a=np.array( [[1, 2, 0],
   [2, 0, 1]])
```